# C Memory management in a client Server application

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am building an [IOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) protocol application on top of TCP. The application is almost complete,
I am currently bench-marking the performance of the application. The application will be embedded on hardware hence memory usage is strict.

I've ran my application within [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)  and got very terrible memory usage stats. 
See valgrind screeshot below.
[image: Valgrind memory profiler]

I have variables declared on the server, these variables have to be accessed by multiple clients(the server is multi-threaded),

Below is how i create variables on the server side

```
#define SERVER_IS_RUNNING 0
int* server_status = malloc(sizeof(*server_status));
*server_status = SERVER_IS_RUNNING;
```

When a clients requests to read/write the server_status variable, the value of server_status is sent back to the client.

Given such a situation, how can i free memory allocated to server_status keeping in mind that the server will be running forever and clients can connect at any given time. If i free the server_variable, it won't have a proper value when the clients tries to read it.

Comment: If you're programming in C, then use only that tag. C and C++ are two very different languages.

Comment: As for management, keep a structure for each client, collecting *all* data needed for that client (including this `server_status` (but not dynamically allocated), the socket itself, and other data you might need for each connection). When a client disconnects, release this structure and all its dynamically allocated data.

Comment: Why do you use malloc at all? Simply declare server_status as an int and you are done? Or is the sample code overly simplified?

Comment: @ewramner there a number of services using server_status. Services that extend multiple modules / multiple files. That's the reason for declaring server_status as a pointer.

Comment: If you have multiple "services", each requiring a separate and distinct "server_status", then perhaps you should have an *array* of "all_server_status"? At least it would lessen fragmentation.

Comment: I'm still not with you. If there is a single pointer to an int it uses a single memory location that is shared by all the services, right? If so making it an int and passing &server_status to the clients should be exactly the same, except that there is no malloc involved and hence no leak?